# How to publish master pages in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, master-pages, publishing

How do you publish master pages in Visual Studio? Neither Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 seems to publish master pages over my ftp profile, creating the need to manually transfer the master pages in an ftp client.

Comment: are they set to Content?

Comment: Thanks, that turned out to be the problem. If you add an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: i have provided my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the master pages are set to Content.